# Is V a Vectorspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I want to show that $V$ is a vectorspace.

Let $K = \mathbb{R}$ and $V= (\mathbb{R}^{2\times1}, \oplus,\odot)$ and $\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{2\times1}$

with $\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix} \oplus\begin{pmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \end{pmatrix} := \begin{pmatrix} x_1 + y_1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$
and $ \lambda\odot \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix} := \begin{pmatrix} \lambda x_1 \\ \lambda x_2 \end{pmatrix}, \lambda \in \mathbb{R}$.

Now we could just check if all vectorspace axioms are fullfilled (that would require alot of writing and doesn't seem smart).

So my take on this is that we just show that $V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 1}$ ($V$ is a vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{2 \times 1}$) because if V is a subspace, it is by definition a vectorspace.

Alright, let's start.

1. $ V \neq \emptyset$
2. Completion under addition
3. Completion under scalarmultiplication

(1) Because if $x_1 = 0$ and $y_1 = 0$ we get $\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix} \oplus \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ y_2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0+0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ We have $0v \in V$ therefore $ V \neq \emptyset$

(2) Suppose $\overrightarrow{x},\overrightarrow{y} \in V$ and $\overrightarrow{x} = \begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2\end{pmatrix}, \overrightarrow{y} = \begin{pmatrix}y_1 \\ y_2\end{pmatrix}, x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2 \in \mathbb{R}$.

Now $\overrightarrow{x} \oplus \overrightarrow{y} = \begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2\end{pmatrix}\oplus \begin{pmatrix}y_1 \\ y_2\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}x_1+y_1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{2\times1}$. Therefore $V$ is completed under addition.

(3) Suppose $\overrightarrow{x} \in V $ and $\overrightarrow{x} = \begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2\end{pmatrix}, x_1,x_2,\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$.

Now $\lambda \odot \overrightarrow{x} = \lambda \odot \begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \lambda x_1 \\ \lambda x_2\end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{2\times1}$. Therefore V is completed under scalarmultiplication.

With (1),(2),(3) we've shown that $V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{2\times1}$. Because $V$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{2\times1}$ we've shown that $V$ must be a vectorspace.

Can someone check if this proof is valid? I'm really confused because of the $\odot$ and $\oplus$.

EDIT-EDIT-EDIT-EDIT-EDIT-EDIT-EDIT-EDIT-EDIT-EDIT-EDIT-EDIT-EDIT

Alright, now I have another kinda similar problem to this one.

Let $K = \mathbb{R}$ and $U= (\mathbb{R}^{3\times1}, \oplus,\odot)$ and $\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2  \\ x_3 \end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \\ y_3 \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{3\times1}$

with $\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x3 \end{pmatrix} \oplus\begin{pmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \\ y3 \end{pmatrix} := \begin{pmatrix} x_1 + y_1 + 3 \\ x_2 + y_2 + 3 \\ x_3 + y_3 + 3 \end{pmatrix}$
and $ \lambda\odot \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{pmatrix} := \begin{pmatrix} \lambda x_1 \\ \lambda x_2 \\ \lambda x_3  \end{pmatrix}, \lambda \in \mathbb{R}$.

Now if I understood your answers correctly we can just say that $U$ is not a vectorspace because

Let $a \in U$ then $2 \odot a = (a) \oplus (a)$ must be true, which is not the case because: $2 \odot \begin{pmatrix} a_1 \\ a_2 \\ a_3 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 2 \cdot a_1 \\ 2 \cdot a_2 \\ 2 \cdot a_3 \end{pmatrix}$ but
$(a) \oplus (a) = \begin{pmatrix} a_1 + a_1 + 3 \\ a_2 + a_2 + 3 \\  a_1 + a_1 + 3\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 2a_1 + 3\\ 2a_2 + 3 \\  2a_3 + 3\end{pmatrix}$

Or am I missing something?

Comment: So $2\odot \binom xy = \binom {2x}{2y}$?   But $\binom xy\oplus \binom xy =\binom {x+y}0$.  Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: Yes, this is what the $\odot$ and $\oplus$ operations are supposed to do.

Comment: How does $2\odot \binom{x}{y}$ compare to $(1+1)\odot \binom{x}{y}$?  How does $(1+1)\odot \binom{x}{y}$ compare to $(1\odot \binom{x}{y})\oplus (1\odot \binom{x}{y})$?  Among those vector space axioms you skipped are several involving how distributivity and associativity and such work... and they happened to not work here.

Comment: @jenny  so...you see where there is a problem, right?  You need $2\odot \vec v=\vec v \oplus \vec v$.

Comment: Now... if you have a parent vectorspace *who you have already proven to be a vectorspace* and as such have already proven associativity and distributivity and all the other boring axioms and you ask if a subset of the space is a sub*space*, then yes... since the associativity properties and such were all proven for the parent space we don't need to prove them again for the proposed child subspace because it inherits those properties.  Here for this problem however, we don't have a parent space that we proved the properties for to inherit from and so they may *not* have been skipped.

Comment: Hm.. For $(1\odot \binom{x}{y})\oplus (1\odot \binom{x}{y})$ we could write $a = \binom{x}{y}$ and then we get $(a)\oplus (a) = \binom{x+y}{0}$ but it should be $\binom{2x}{2y}$

Comment: Also of note the only Subspaces of $R^2$ are the zero subspace, $R^2$ itself, and the lines through the origin.

Comment: I've added a second part to this question with another problem similar to the first one just  so i can be sure I understood correctly, thanks for the responses so far!

Comment: Yes, your argument is good for the second one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Important point: You *can't* just use the subspace test with $\mathbb{R^2}$ because, first of all, $V = \mathbb{R}^{2}$ (as a set) and is not a subset. But more importantly, **$\mathbb{R^{2}}$ has different operations** (in the way you're thinking of it). A subspace must have the same operations, and clearly $+$ doesn't (I'm just gonna call $\oplus$ as +). It is an important subtlety and you should make sure you understood this.

So if given $V \subseteq W$, where $W$ is a known vector space, to check that $V$ is a vector *sub*space we would need that $V$ inherits the same operations from $W$. Otherwise $V$ must be treated as its own thing, and you must check from scratch.

Now that being said, the space you described is *not* a vector space.

For one thing there's no additive identity. For example, given $(1, 2)$, no matter what we choose as our identity, say, $(0, 0)$, we don't retain $(1,2)$. In this case, $(1, 2) + (0, 0) = (1, 0) \not = (1,2)$. More generally you will never retain the second entry if it is non zero.

As noted in the comments, associativity isn't satisfied either. This object fails being a vector space pretty badly!